# PHP Session handler Redis - AWS ElastiCache Encryption in-transit

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I've tried to setup PHP session handler Redis.

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://xxx.cache.amazonaws.com:6379"
```

This works well, but when Encryption in-transit is enabled, then it fails on

> Failed to read session data: redis

In that case connection string contained auth param

> ?auth=12345

Is there any trick which I've missed

Comment: Redis currently doesn't support TLS. The TLS layer is provided by AWS elasticache. The phpredis client which you're using won't be able to connect to the Elasticache when Encryption is enabled.

Comment: Thanks, I've reached same conclusion, I just thought somebody might have some trick in a sleeve

Comment: Redis versions 6 and 7 from AWS Elasticache now support TLS that is compatible with PHP Sessions and Predis.  With those, you can use the `tls://` syntax provided by Zdenek below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, not documented very well, but https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/1657 pointed me in right direction, solution is simple, use tls scheme

```
session.save_path = "tls://xxx.cache.amazonaws.com:6379?auth=12345"
```

Comment: Had the same problem - fixed by this solution. gracias